# Open hyperlink in another web view control

Tags: java, swing, webview, javafx-2, javafx

I want to open link in another web view control on clicking the hyperlinks in another web 
   view in swing using Java FX

> Actually i am having two web view controls A n B on the same screen . 
>   On clicking the hyperlink in a , new link should be opened in B web
>   view control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Allow webviewA to open content in webviewB**

Use [setCreatePopupHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#setCreatePopupHandler%28javafx.util.Callback%29):

```
webviewA.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler(new Callback<PopupFeatures, WebEngine>() {
  @Override public WebEngine call(PopupFeatures popupFeatures) {
    return webviewB.getEngine();
  }
});
```

Or, if you are using jdk8 and don't like typing:

```
webviewA.getEngine().setCreatePopupHandler(
  popupFeatures -> webviewB.getEngine()
);
```

**Make your html links open content in a new window**

Define the hyperlinks in the document loaded in `webviewA` using `target="_blank"`

For example:

```
webviewA.loadContent(
  "<a href='http://sundae.triumf.ca/pub2/cave/node001.html' target='_blank'>" +
    "XYZZY" +
  "</a>"
);
```

when you click on the hyperlink and utter the magic word, it will open the Colossal Cave adventure in `webviewB`.